# Awk search for regex stored in file1 in file2

Tags: regex, file, search, awk

I have the following problem:

I have 2 files. file1 containing starting-strings (headers) for my search in file 2.

File1 looks like:

```
header1
header5
header17
header1076
...
```

And file2 containing data in the format:

```
>header
XXXX
>header2
XXXX
XXXX
XXX
>header3
X
```

So I want a file called header2 with information

```
>header2
XXXX
XXXX
XXX
```

if header2 is present in file1.

Now I want to extract the entries of file2 into a seperate file name like the header when the header is present in file1. I have a functioning awk script for extracting entries but I have to specify the regex + filename by hand:

```
awk '/header1/{p=1;print $0;next} /^>/{p=0} p{print}' file2 > ~/Desktop/single_scaffolds/header1
```

I know I could probably just invoke my extraction script with input from file1 by some bash-code or similar, but I think its possible to solve it purely in awk.

So far I tried:

```
awk ' 
FNR==NR {  
    scafArray[$0] = $0
}
for (entry in scafArray){

/entry/{p=1;print $0;next} /^>/{p=0} p{print > "~/Desktop/single_scaffolds/adjacent_sequence/"entry};
exit;

}' file1 file2
```

But I keep getting errors. I am not very proficient in awk so any help is welcome :)

EDIT: An additional Idea I had is to extract them all in one go when just parsing 1 time through file2, so I dont have to search through the file multiple times (file2 may be gigabytes large and I may want to extract entries in the hundreds), but then I really have no idea how to do that ;)

EDIT2: I am actually not sure if its faster to look for every line in my 1mio line file if it matches to one of my hundred headers (like 1mio * max. 100 look ups) or to search 100 times through the file for 1 header and exit after i found him (like 100 * max. 1mio comparissons)

Comment: Could you show what is the exact structure of file1? are headers unique in file1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are as in your examples, you can load an array from file1 such that the indices will be exact matches for the lines in file2 that should trigger the output.

That way the look-ups will be hash-map searches, constant time, much more efficient than looping through 100 possible things to match on (or passing through the file 100 times), so hopefully the performance won't be too bad:

**EDIT**: Version that prints to file based on header name:

```
NR==FNR { a[">" $0]; next }
$0 in a {fn = substr($0, 2); p = 1; print > fn; next}
/^>/ {p = 0}
p { print > fn }
```

Original answer:

```
$ cat asr.awk
NR==FNR { a[">" $0]; next }
$0 in a {p = 1; print $0; next}
/^>/ {p = 0}
p

$ cat file1
header2
header5
header17
header1076

$ cat file2
>header1
X1
>header2
XXXX2
XXXX2
XXX2
>header3
X3
XXXX3
>header5
aaa
aaaa
a
>header18
bbb
bbbb
bb

$ awk -f asr.awk file1 file2
>header2
XXXX2
XXXX2
XXX2
>header5
aaa
aaaa
a
```

Comment: Wow, that looks way easier than I expected. Now if I wanted to store the output in a file called like the header i assume i could add something after the print $0? Like {p = 1;filename = /path/to/file/$0; print $0 > filename; next} and at the end p{print $0 >> filename} ?

Comment: Yep, see edit. (Note that I removed the `>` from the front of the filename. It's not strictly necessary to do that but unless there's some kind of requirement to have it there, life would probably be simpler without it. ;)

Comment: Also note that `print $0` and `print` are equivalent. Finally, within the same awk run, you generally only need to use single `>` to redirect output. The first one will (re)create an empty file and the rest will all append. You only need `>>` if you want to append to a file as it was from before the invocation of awk.

Comment: Nevermind I was to slow ;), thanks for the great answer.

_Shouldnt the second print be with >> so it does not override the header-line in the file from the first print?_

Comment: See here for a better explanation of `>` versus `>>`:  http://porthos.ist.utl.pt/docs/gawk/gawk_6.html#SEC67